# tcl constrained wild card

Tags: tcl, wildcard

I wish to add a tcl wildcard which allows the following strings
str[3]   OR str[4]  OR str[5]

I don't wish to add a wild card as str\[*] as this includes other str[0-2] as-well.

Can you please let me know how this can be done ?

it included all str[*].

Comment: Hi, could you explain the context where you are trying to use this?  Is it in `string match`, `regexp`, `glob` or something else?  It makes a difference whether you are in a context that requires glob-style patterns or regex-style patterns.

Comment: I am using this is string matches

Comment: `string match` uses glob-style patterns, so Donal's answer should do the job.

Answer (score 1):

Glob-style wildcards can do this with `str\[[345]\]` (you'll probably want to put that in braces as it has both backslashes and square brackets in it). The same sequence happens to also be a valid regular expression to match the same thing (though unanchored); that isn't true in general, but is here.

I tend to use REs for tokenizing.